# Jump to mark command (backtick) not working

Tags: vim

After setting a mark, I can't jump to it using `` `<mark> ``, it doesn't work. However `'<mark>` works. What could be wrong?

Comment: If you start Vim like this: `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N` do you still have the same problem? Are you using a normal english keyboard layout? Are you using MacVim/GVim/just Vim?

Comment: check output of :verbose map `  if there is a line starting with n?

Comment: @Daan, I do still have the same problem. They keyboard laytout is br-abnt2. I don't know much about terminal configurations, but I believe the keymap is configured accordingly, at least I get the expected output from all the keys when typing text. No MacVim/Gvim, just plain Vim.

Comment: @Kent. Yes, the two entries lines from the output start with "n". I am sorry, I tried to format it so you could read it more easily, but aparently neither code blocks or line breaks work on comments:

n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim

Comment: Are you trying to create marks in a netrw window?

Comment: What would be the chances that your keyboard sends an accented letter instead of a ` followed by a character?

Comment: @romainl.

That is exactly what is happening. The keyboard driver is trying to send an accented letter. So it works with `<Space><mark>. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI: vim-signature does remap this by default: `n  \`]          * :<C-U>call signature#mark#Goto("next", "spot", "alpha")<CR>`

Answer (score 1):

When using MacVim the option `Draw marked text inline` may be the culprit.

Go to Settings->Advanced and make sure the corresponding checkbox is disabled.

Comment: thanks for this answer, as neither ' or ` were working for me

Answer (score 0):

do a `:map<CR>` and check if nothing overmapped the " ` " char (dumb plugins does dumb things), also if you keybord is configured right, sometimes latin chars are a mess, unfortunately...